# PowerShell, Get-ChildItem formatted output

Tags: powershell, string-formatting, get-childitem

I have various simple functions like the below (this one outputs Size in 'human readable' format and the Name) and am curious on generic ways to format outputs for these functions.

- How can I make the size column all right-justified, but have all file/folder names be left-justifed in their own column?
- How can I replace "`t" by column sizing that takes into account the max width of the size column  (over all, including the [D] directory lines) and have an intelligent tab that is 2 char bigger than the max size?
- How can I make the directories sort first (I don't see how to do that in PowerShell so easily)?

```
function d ($name) {   # quick and dirty Size + Name
    $out = ""
    function Format-FileSize([int64]$size) {
        if ($size -gt 1TB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} TB", $size / 1TB)}
        elseif ($size -gt 1GB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0} GB", $size / 1GB)}
        elseif ($size -gt 1MB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0} MB", $size / 1MB)}
        elseif ($size -gt 1KB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0} KB", $size / 1KB)}
        elseif ($size -gt 0) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0} B", $size)}
        else {""}
    }
    foreach ($i in (gci $folder | sort Length).FullName) {
        if (Test-Path -Path $i -PathType Container) {
            $size = "[DIR]"
            $size_out = "[DIR]" 
        }
        else {
            $size = (gci $i | select Length).Length
            $size_out = Format-FileSize($size)
            $size_total += $size
        }
        $out += "$size_out`t$(split-path $i -leaf)`n"
    }
    $out += "========`n$(Format-FileSize($size_total))  Total Size"
    $out
}
```

Example of how I would like the output to look:

```
   [DIR]  0
   [DIR]  Setup
   [DIR]  Stuff
 69.0  B  Profiler.url
480.0  B  test-countdown.ps1
  1.0 KB  PinToTaskbar.ps1
  3.5 KB  Firefox2.reg
 70.5 KB  Firefox1.reg
124.7 KB  elevate.exe
  9.2 MB  Stardock Fences 4.0.0.3.exe
112.5 MB  pandoc.exe
 12.1 GB  image.iso
========
 12.2 GB  Total Size
```

Comment: https://github.com/santisq/PSTree similar to what you're looking for but displaying the objects with hierarchy

Comment: That is a fantastic tool (and I will make good use of that and look forward to your further development of it), though I am still quite interested in generic ways to format outputs similar to the OP.